# Unset php var when statement = "all"

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I try to unset my variabele when the input is not "all" in a selection of radioboxes. The if statemtent works and does the job perfectly, but the else doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
$profile = $_POST["profile"];

if ($profile != 'all') { 
    $conditions["profile"] = $profile; 
} else { 
    unset($conditions["profile"]);
}
```

Comment: How do you know it does not work. Do you have an error message you would like to share with us?

Comment: Does `$conditions["profile"]` actually exist before you attempt to unset it

Comment: `unset($profile)` maybe? `unset($_POST["profile"])`? as @RiggsFolly said; make sure it exists before trying to unset it. `unset(whatever_exists)`.

Comment: Well, you can specify your profile with different radio buttons. So if profile = "all" it has to show every profile from the database that matches your profile. If they check radio button 'brown hair' for example, it shows less results(with a live update, no refresh). But when you tick the radio button 'all' back on instead of 'brown hair' it still only gives the results as if you checked 'brown hair'. That's because at the first page load I do a get all from the database, but from the moment something's changed on the form I do a search query.

Answer (score 0):

I think your $_POST variable may not be set. Try something like this:

either:

```
$profile = isset($_POST["profile"]) ? $_POST["profile"] : 'all';
```

or within the else block:

```
} else { 

    if(isset($conditions["profile"])) unset($conditions["profile"]);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, and I'm pretty sure it is set. Because at first I do a get all on my form than it shows all the results. From the moment there's a change on the form I use a search API. So at first 'all' is checked. and getAll gives all the results. Then when you change 'all' to 'brown hair' (for example). It works fine and it gives all the profiles that matches the profile 'brown haird'. But when I want to check 'all' back again, it still gives the results as if 'brown hair' was checked. And that's the problem I'm having

Comment: So it seems you are having an issue overwriting the $_POST["profile"] value on the form re-submit event. Without seeing the code it is shooting in the dark but have you tried some debug to see why is the old value lingering in the POST variable after re-submission? Can you post more code ?